# Python - nested list comprehension with tokenizing

Tags: python, list, nested, list-comprehension

Python question: I have a list of sentences on which I want to apply nltk stemming. So for each word in each sentence, I want to apply, in this case, the nltk snowball.stem function.

I want to write that as short as possible via list comprehension.
Below code works fine, but I want to write it in less lines:

```
data_stemming=[]
for sentence in data:
    word_list=word_tokenize(sentence)
    stemmed_sentence=' '.join([stemmer.stem(w) for w in word_list])
    data_stemming.append(stemmed_sentence)

print(data_stemming)
```

output:

```
['do do done', 'do requir', 'shoe shoe']
```

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`nltk.word_tokenize` accepts as input a `string`, but `data` is a **list** of strings. What you need is:

```
data = ['doing do done', 'requires require', 'shoe shoes']
joined_data = ' '.join(data)
data_stemming=[[snowball.stem(w) for w in word_list] for word_list in nltk.word_tokenize(joined_data)]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but the output is a bit different than expected. I would like to have the outcome in the same format as the input, i.e. a list of sentences: data_stemming=['do do do', 'require require', 'shoe shoe'] 

(Something like this, not sure what the stemming will do exactly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it in a single List comprehension

```
data_stemming = [''.join([stemmer.stem(w) for w in word_tokenize]) for sentence in data]
```